# On trying to add gitlab ci to build my project using SSH executor, I get the error "asn1: structure error: superfluous leading zeros in length"

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab, openstack

On searching for the reason for this issue, I read that it is due to a problem with the key file and most people change the ssh key to work around it.
However, it is not an option for me since I have a specific openstack instance used to build this project. I am able to use this ssh key file to log into it. 
Any pointers as to why this issue may occur only for gitlab executor and how to resolve it?

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.4.0 (857480b6)
  on build config_api (7988f6db)
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: asn1: structure error: superfluous leading zeros in length
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: asn1: structure error: superfluous leading zeros in length
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: asn1: structure error: superfluous leading zeros in length
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): asn1: structure error: superfluous leading zeros in length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution(or workaround) for my case was to make a new ssh key pair and add the new public key also to the authorised_keys file in the build server. With the new private key I registered my runner again and it worked.

The method I used is described in this link:
[Howto use multiple SSH keys for password less login](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-multiple-ssh-key-based-authentication.html)